# Navbar doesn't function in angular with bootstrap and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Angular 7 with bootstrap, jQuery and popperJS; The styles and navbar opens as expected and routing is working but the navbar doesn't auto close when an item is clicked on nor does it do so if somewhere else than navbar is clicked on.

My app component:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-purple fixed-top navbar-dark shadow-sm" id="navigationBar" role="navigation">
  <div class="container my-1">
    <div>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="padding-top: 0.3rem; padding-bottom: 0.3rem"><span class="h2" id="navbar-brand"><span>Brand</span></a>
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="navbar-toggler border-0" data-target="#navbarMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbarMenu" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" data-toggle="collapse" routerLink="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white-80" data-toggle="collapse" routerLink="/skills">Skills</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white-80" data-toggle="collapse" routerLink="/projects">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white-80" data-toggle="collapse" routerLink="/socials">Socials</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

App component ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

I have included the required scripts:

```
"scripts": [
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
          "./src/app/js/strange.js"
],
```

And the styles:

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
],
```

And I cannot figure out how to make the navbar pills active dynamically as per the route.

Comment: Please, edit and post your `component.ts`

Comment: Added, Please have a look as soon as you can :)

Comment: Doesn't navbar need initialization from js? + `I cannot figure out how to make the navbar pills active dynamically as per the route.` use https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive.

Comment: Thanks for that! Can you look into the navbar not auto-closing? it's been eating me alive for hours!

Comment: `routerLinkActive="active"`. It will add the class "active", if the router link the current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet should work.

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $(document).click(event => {
        let clickover = $(event.target);
        let opened = $('.navbar-collapse').hasClass('show');
        if (opened === true && !clickover.hasClass('navbar-toggler')) {
            $('.navbar-toggler').click();
        }
    });
});
```

> And I cannot figure out how to make the navbar pills active
>   dynamically as per the route.

[RouterLinkActive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) will do the job.

Comment: Marked as accepted but I still wanted to thank you so; Thanks! It works like a charm!!

Comment: @SidSun No problem. I am glad that I could help.